# Python- Look for string only in the beginning of a string

Tags: python, string, diff

I am using `difflib.Differ()` on two lists.

The way Differ works, it appends a `+` if a line is unique to sequence 2 and a `-` if a line is unique to sequence 1. It appends this right at the beginning of the sequence.

I want to search for sequences in my list that begin with `-` or `+` but only if the string begins with this character as the majority of my sequences have these characters in other places within the string.

In the code snippet below, `diff_list` is the list. I want it to check for a `+` or `-` in the very first place in the string value of every sequence in this list:

```
for x in diff_list:
    if "+" or "-" in x[0]:
        print x
```

This output seems to print all of the lines even those that don't begin with `-` or `+`

Comment: `"+" or "-" in x[0]:` is always True, since `"+"` is always True, you wanted - `"+"  in x[0] or "-" in x[0]:` or if `x` is string, - `x[0] in ['+','-']` .

Comment: Thank you. How do I mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: You cannot mark comments as correct answer. You can answer the question and mark it as correct if you want to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try startswith?

```
s = '+asdf'  # sample data

if s.startswith('+') or s.startswith('-'):
    pass  # do work here
```

Docs:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

Comment: I did not know about this. Thank you

Comment: I think it's more readable.  As a bonus, it is not limited to just 1 character.  Also note there is an endswith too.